# Convert MySQL command to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The command is

```
SELECT *
FROM txactions
WHERE acccount_id = 1565
  AND recon_status = 2
  AND date_posted BETWEEN <var date1> and <var date2>
ORDER BY date_poste
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Models? Associations? And what's wrong with using plain SQL? This question needs some serious improvement for an adequate answer to appear.

Comment: Dude - Its Active Record. Use the naming conventions. And I can't use Plain SQL

Comment: It depends on how your associaions and scopes are defined, these can make this query much shorter. ActiveRecord abstracts most of the query details into reusable pieces. If you're not doing that, you'll get queries about as ugly as SQL itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a very specific problem that will most probably not help any other user in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Txaction.where("account_id = 1565 AND recon_status = 2 AND date_posted BETWEEN ? and ?", @date1, @date2).order("date_posted").first
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is AR query:

```
Txaction.where(acccount_id: 1565, recon_status: 2, date_posted: date1..date2)
        .order(:date_posted)
        .first
```